# Training Tesseract 3.03 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: tesseract, training-data

I try to train a new font on tesseract, I follow the steps on the official guide but the problem is in the charset extractor phase.
The training app unicharset_extractor gives in output the chars without right properties.
The help say that '**if the system use wctype functions, the value will be set automatically**' but the app say that **wctype is disabled**.
How can I use automatic char properties extraction on Ubuntu?